# "unsupported operand types for +" when trying to print string together with number

Tags: python

I wanted to implement the formula for calculating speed into Python:

```
def speed():
    distance = input("What is the total distance? ")
    time = input("What is the total time taken to get from start to finish? ")
    print("The Speed is ") + int(distance) / int(time)

speed()
```

But whenever I run it, I get this error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'float'
```

How do I do this correctly?

Answer (score 1):

The offending line is:

```
print("The Speed is ") + int(distance) / int(time)
```

1. You'd want *everything* you want to print within the print brackets `()` aka:

```
print("The Speed is " + int(distance) / int(time))
```

2. You can only add like types together, so you'll have to either explicitly cast your math to a `str`:

```
print("The Speed is " + str(int(distance) / int(time)))
```

- Or, for what I find to be a cleaner approach, use f-strings:

```
print(f"The Speed is {int(distance) / int(time)}")
```

Comment: I tried using the comment you made just now, ```print("The speed is " + int(distance) / int(time))``` and it gave this error: ```TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "float") to str```

Comment: Yes, you'll need step two rather than just step one to get a result~

Comment: Ah I see, I understand now. As the variables have to be wrapped around an str() and an int() which was not clear to me at the time, thanks for the help all